# Removing NAs before calculating a grouped statistic

Tags: r

How do I define the removal of NAs prior to calculating the standard deviation of a variable per group? I'm using ave() like so:

`df$sd_grade1 <- ave(df$grade1, df$class, FUN = sd)`

"Grade 1" is a numeric variable from 1 to 7 and it consists one NA value. I want to calculate the standard deviation of the variable "Grade 1" grouped per class (class has two groups, "math" and "english"). 
The problem is, if there is a single NA value in "Grade 1" and it's in math in df$class, all values for standard deviation for math become NAs.
Ungrouped it's not a problem, NAs are removed correctly before SD is calculated like so:

`df$sd_grade1 <- sd(df$grade1, na.rm = TRUE)`

Basically, I want to omit any NAs that appear in "Grade 1" when calculating the standard deviation per group in a new variable. With ave() and na.rm = TRUE I get an error, na.omit = TRUE returns no error but doesn't do anything either. How do I correctly define it with ave()?

Reproducible:

```
df <- data.frame(
  grade1 = sample(1:10),
  class = sample(c("maths", "english"), 10, replace = TRUE)
)

df$grade1<-car::recode(df$grade1,"3=NA")

# ungrouped, same SD regardless of group and NAs omitted in SD calculation, but this is not something I want.
df$sd_grade1 <- sd(df$grade1, na.rm = TRUE)

# grouped, but na.rm does not work here because "maths" contains one NA.
df$sd_grp_grade1 <- ave(df$grade1, df$class, FUN =  sd, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: @RonakShah does not work because grade1 consists one NA, therefore the SD for the entire class group is turned to NA.

Comment: @RonakShah I added one just now.

Comment: Thank you for adding an example. What is your expected output instead of `NA` for `maths` `class` ?

Comment: @RonakShah I want the standard deviation calculated for `maths` as if this one NA value weren't there, with the same standard deviation for every observation belonging to `maths` (as it is for english).

Comment: It works with `dplyr` though. `df %>%
  group_by(class) %>%
  mutate(new_sd  = sd(grade1, na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: @RonakShah it works but it returns the same as `df$sd_grade1 <- sd(df$grade1, na.rm = TRUE)`, it's the same standard deviation value for all observations in the variable `grade1` regardless whether it's `maths` or `english`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was so surprised to find this out that

```
ave(df$grade1, df$class, FUN =  sd, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1]   NA 3.35   NA 3.35   NA   NA   NA 3.35 3.35 3.35
```

returns `NA` for all the values if there is even one single `NA` in the group.

I then changed the function and checked for `sum` and surprisingly `sum` gives the same `NA` values.

```
ave(df$grade1, df$class, FUN =  sum, na.rm = TRUE)
# [1] NA 31 NA 31 NA NA NA 31 31 31
```

After closely looking at the documenatation of `ave` I realised that there is no `...` parameter for `FUN` to pass additional arguments. So `na.rm = TRUE` in the above attempts is not being passed to `sd` as well as `sum`.

So to pass additional parameters we need to use an anonymous function call in `ave`

```
ave(df$grade1, df$class, FUN =  function(x) sd(x, na.rm = TRUE))
#[1] 3.10 3.35 3.10 3.35 3.10 3.10 3.10 3.35 3.35 3.35
```

It also works for `sum` then.

```
ave(df$grade1, df$class, FUN = function(x) sum(x, na.rm = TRUE))
#[1] 21 31 21 31 21 21 21 31 31 31
```

**data**

```
set.seed(589)
df <- data.frame(
  grade1 = sample(1:10),
  class = sample(c("maths", "english"), 10, replace = TRUE))

df$grade1<-car::recode(df$grade1,"3=NA")
```

Answer (score 3):

By using  `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(class) %>% summarise(SD = sd(grade1, 
        na.rm = TRUE))
```

Output:

```
  # A tibble: 2 x 2
  class      SD
  <fct>   <dbl>
1 english  2.63
2 maths    3.65
```